# How to use machine learning to count words in text

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, text-processing, word-count

Question:
Given a piece of text like "This is a test"; how to build a machine learning model to get the number of word occurrences for example in this piece, word count is 4. After training, it is possible to predict text word count.

I know it is easy to write a program (like below pseudo code),

```
data: memory.punctuation['~', '`', '!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', ...]
f: count.word(text) -> count =
   f: tokenize(text) --list-->
   f: count.token(list, filter) where filter(token)<not in memory.punctuation> -> count
```

however in this question, we require to use machine learning algorithm. I wonder how machine can learn the concept of `count` (currently, we know machine learning is good at `classification`). Any idea and suggestions? Thanks in advance.

---

Failures:

We can use sth like word2vec (encoder) to build word vectors; if we consider seq2seq approach, we can train sth like `This is a test <s> 4 <e>` `This is very very long sentence and the word count is greater than ten <s> 4 1 <e>` (4 1 to represent the number 14). However, it does not work since attention model is used to get similar vector for example text translating (`This is a test --> 这(this) 是(is) 一个(a) 测试(test)`). It is hard to find relationship between [`this` ...] and `4` which is an aggregated number (i.e. model not convergent).

We know machine learning is good at classification. If we treat "4" as a class, the number of classes is infinite; if we do a tricky and use `count/text.length` as prediction, i have not got a model that fit even training data set (model not convergent); for example, if we use many short sentence to train the model, it will fail to predict long sentence length. And it may be related to an information paradox: `we can encode data in a book as 0.x and use a machine to to mark a position on a rod to split it into 2 parts with length a and b, where a/b = 0.x; but we cannot find a machine`.

Answer (score 0):

What about a regression problem?

I think it would work quite well and that at the end it will output a nearly whole numbers all the time.

Also you can train a simple RNN to do the job, assuming you are using a hot one encoding and take an output from the last state.
If `V_h` is all zeros but the space index (which will be `1`) and `V_x` as well, than the network will actually sum the spaces, and if `c` is `1` at the end so the output will be the number of words - For every length!

Comment: thank you for suggestion; using a hot one encoding means that you have word vectors already; however, for example like source code text, there are many new-created word which has no vector (infinite one-hot ...); and as noisy data become more and more like `['this', '.', '.', '.', 'is', 'a', 'test']`; we can do some pre-processing to summarize source code token as a `[symbol]` (mask approach); if we do so, it falls back to write a program to count word instead of letting machine to learn how to count ...

Comment: Well I meant each char would be a token so if you are only in English you have about  100, which is very reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can take it as a classification problem for a character being the input and `if word breaker` as the output.

In other words, at some time point *t*, we output whether the input character at the same time point is a word breaker (YES) or not (NO). If yes, then increase the word count. If no, then read the next character.

In modern English language I don't think there are going to be long words. So simple RNN model should do perhaps without the concern of vanishing gradient.

Let me know what you think!

Comment: it is good idea; however, we use a written program to count word (use a variable and do increase count); what i want is to let machine to learn how to count ...
and counting for example source code, we have text like `int main (int argc, const char* argv[]) { return 0; }`; when there are many noise the model will not convergent (it does not work on counting words, so it cannot count how many function defined either).

Answer (score 0):

Use NLTK for counting words,

`from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
 text = "God is Great!"
 word_count = len(word_tokenize(text))
 print(word_count)`

Comment: in your case, native lib can also do this like: `import re; len( filter(lambda x: x, re.split('[^\w]+', 'God is Great!')) )`

Comment: yes, I agree. But the reason I suggested NLTK is that it may/can be used for other purposes in NLP.

Comment: but my question is how computer can generate the NLTK code or my one line code by computer itself.